# iOS - Use AVPlayerViewController in AVKit obj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, avkit

I am trying to update this deprecated method:
'presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated'
however I am not able to import AVKit and use AVPlayerViewContoller. It seems like my Xcode is not seeing this framework somehow.

Here is my code:

*MatchDetailsVC.m*

```
   -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
YoutubeVideoModel* video = [_videos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController *videoPlayerViewController = [[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideoIdentifier:video.videoID];
   =>[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerViewController];
```

*Cannot access the AVKit files:*
[using CM + click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYehF.png)

*MatchDetalisVC.m* UPDATE

```
[self presentViewController:videoPlayerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Changed the last line with this. No errors. It seems I don't have to #import AVKit in my ViewController as well. Is it correct though?

Comment: what do your `#import`s look like? what error do you get?

Comment: File not found. I have tried "AVKit.h", "AVPlayerViewController.h".

Comment: Try `#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>`

Comment: There is no error now, but I can't get through any of AVKit.h files. Getting question mark constantly. Which method use to rebuild my call with presentMovie?

Comment: I think you need to show some more code and the question marks.

Comment: I have added an image with this situation.

Answer (score 4):

added this line, just working

```
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>
```